# Can I programming OpenGL4+ in a card that support 2.1 only?

Tags: c++, c, opengl

This is the OpenGL version I have:

```
Video Card Vendor:    Intel
Renderer:             Intel(R) HD Graphics
OpenGL Version:       2.1.0 - Build 8.15.10.2622
GLU Version:          1.2.2.0 Microsoft Corporation
```

I'd like to learn the latest OpenGL API. But my card supports only 2.1 (and I cant update). Is it possible to program in latest API even with no card support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AshleysBrain's answer is not quite correct. You can use a software implementation of OpenGL such as [Mesa3D](http://www.mesa3d.org/) which can execute newer code using your CPU instead of your GPU. It will be slower but will allow you to compile and run <s>your 4+ code against it</s> OpenGL 3.1 code against it.

Edit: just checked, it seems Mesa only supports up to OpenGL 3.1. Still; that's pretty good for free.

Answer (score 2):

It's more to do with what version the driver supports.  Try updating your driver and see if it supports a newer version.  Otherwise I'm afraid you're stuck with that version, there's nothing else you can do!

Comment: Disagree with "there's nothing else you can do".

Comment: likewise... close but no cigar

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Send money/time [Mesa's](http://www.mesa3d.org/) way in the hope they'll support GL4 in their software rasterizer sometime soon.</strike>

Or pester [Khronos](http://www.khronos.org/opengl) for a reference implementation.

[As of Mesa 20.2 `llvmpipe` supports OpenGL 4.5](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/-/blob/mesa-20.2.0/docs/features.txt#L213).

Answer (score 0):

Intel(R) HD Graphics are usually onboard.So NO you can't use GPU accelerated OpenGL 4.2 with this.You need dedicated card like those of Nvidia.The highest version of OpenGL I have seen on the dedicated cards is 3.1 which still delivers fixed pipeline API with Shaders support.But OpenGL 4.2 has completely removed all this and uses programmable way of doing things which requires programmable hardware too.